# WYSIWIG/Markdown editor with Angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, markdown, angular-material, wysiwyg

Whether there any WYSIWIG editor available in Angular JS which don't have the bootstrap dependency? I have tried many of the the editors all those has the dependency with bootstrap.

Note: Am using Angular Material for the pages and not using any bootstrap with my pages

Comment: Someone please help

Comment: Someone please help